# How does one fix the insufficient memory error in uploading to Apple Books?

Tags: icloud, memory, books

I am running Big Sur 11.5.1.

Occasionally when uploading non-Apple ebooks, I get a message that there's insufficient iCloud storage.

In fact, I have 150Gb free on my iCloud account.

Searching via Google, the only suggestion I can find is that this is due to an iCloud format corruption, and the only option is to delete all the books on iCloud, and start again. I can't do this because Apple does not permit the deletion of purchased books.

Is there another way to eliminate this “insufficient memory” bug?